# grouping by unstructured text columns to pivot data

Tags: r

I have some text data which looks like:

```
   ID                      text
1                              
2                              
3                              
4  HD                 some text
5  LP            some more text
6  AN            even more text
7                              
8                              
9                              
10 HD       some different text
11 SN  some more different text
12 AN  even more different text
```

Eac part is a document and its separated by some blank spaces. The document starts with the `ID` as `HD` and ends with the `ID` and `AN`. I am trying to do two things, ultimately I want to `pivot_wider` the data and have the columns as the `ID` and each row would then be a document. I run the following:

```
widerText <- textData %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = text)


finalText <- widerText %>% 
  unnest(HD, LP, AN, SN, PP, LO, AN)
```

Which does not preserve the correct structure and the text gets mixed up. So, I want to create a grouping variable before I run `pivot_wider`.

Each document begins with `HD` and ends with `AN` so I would like to create something with the following output:

Expected output:

```
   ID                      text   grp
1                                  0
2                                  0
3                                  0
4  HD                 some text    1
5  LP            some more text    1
6  AN            even more text    1
7                                  0
8                                  0
9                                  0
10 HD       some different text    2
11 SN  some more different text    2
12 AN  even more different text    2
```

Data:

```
textData <- data.frame(
  ID = c(
    " ", " ", " ", "HD", "LP", "AN",
    " ", " ", " ", "HD", "SN", "AN",
    " ", " ", " ", "HD", "PP", "AN",
    " ", " ", " ", "HD", "LO", "AN"

    ),
  text = c(
    " ", " ", " ", "some text", "some more text", "even more text",
    " ", " ", " ", "some different text", "some more different text", "even more different text",
    " ", " ", " ", "some additional text", "some more additional text", "even more additional text",
    " ", " ", " ", "some extra text", "some more extra text", "even more extra text"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` on `textData$ID == "HD"` to get the groups, and set teh empty ones to `0` using `ifelse`.

```
textData$grp <- ifelse(textData$ID==" ", 0, cumsum(textData$ID == "HD"))
textData
#   ID                      text grp
#1                                 0
#2                                 0
#3                                 0
#4  HD                 some text   1
#5  LP            some more text   1
#6  AN            even more text   1
#7                                 0
#8                                 0
#9                                 0
#10 HD       some different text   2
#11 SN  some more different text   2
#12 AN  even more different text   2
#13                                0
#14                                0
#15                                0
#16 HD      some additional text   3
#17 PP some more additional text   3
#18 AN even more additional text   3
#19                                0
#20                                0
#21                                0
#22 HD           some extra text   4
#23 LO      some more extra text   4
#24 AN      even more extra text   4
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
textData %>%
   mutate(grp_id = case_when(ID==" " ~ 0,
           TRUE ~  cumsum(ID == "HD")))
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
setDT(textData)[,grp_id:=fifelse(ID==" ",0,rleid(ID==" ")/2)]
```

or using `rleid`